# Why this script isn't working

Tags: javascript

After learning basics of C++ i'm now startign to learn Javascript, i just created my first script but it isn't working, and im not able to figure out why.

Here is my index.html code:

```
<head>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>


</head>


<body>

<p id="result">Click button below for result</p>

    <br>

    <button type="button" onClick="math()">Click me</button>

</body>
```

And here is my javascript.js:

```
function (math) {

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'It works';
```

}

Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: change function (math) to function math()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typo issue. Try this:

```
function math() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'It works';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess i need some rest haha :)

Comment: OK. Please accept this answer. Since you're a new guy in stackoverflow, read [http://stackoverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). This site will help you much in your future career.

Comment: Typo's shouldn't be answered, they should be closed, there is a specific close reason for them